# I'm not able to see the text after adding Lottie animation

Tags: ios, swift3, lottie

I need help.
I have Intwgrate a `Lottie` but I'm unable to see the text which is in the button which is need to display after expanding the button. 
So does `LotAnimationView` supports the text rendering? 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The Lottie Team haven't yet implemented support for text layers.  But you can right click on your text layer and select "Create shapes from text" and animate that shape layer.

For more details on what is supported go to:

http://airbnb.io/lottie/supported-features.html